# Evaluate the integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1 + e^x}dx\;$ where $\;0<a<1\;.$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-writing

I have to evaluate : $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1 +  e^x}dx\;$ where $\;0<a<1\;.$

I know that we have :

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1 +  e^x}dx =\lim\limits_{R \to \infty}\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{e^{ax}}{1 +  e^x}dx =$

$\displaystyle\quad=\lim\limits_{R \to \infty}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{ax}}{1 +  e^x}dx - \int_{C_R} \frac{e^{ax}}{1 +  e^x}dx$

For C$_R$ half-circle runs $R$ from $-R$ and $\gamma_R$ a closed contour.

I have a hint: try other closures than C$_R\;.$

Comment: It is also "simple" without complex analysis if you enjoy the gaussian hypergeometric function.

Comment: we can also use Beta function to evaluate the integral. Making change $t=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ we get $e^{ax}=\Bigl(\frac{1-t}{t}\Bigr)^a$ and $I(a)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^2}\Bigl(\frac{1-t}{t}\Bigr)^a\frac{t}{1-t}t=\int_0^{\infty} (1-t)^{a-1}t^{-a}dt=B(a;1-a)=\Gamma(a)\Gamma(1-a)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi a}$

Answer (score 4):

$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1 + e^x}dx$$

Using the following contour and periodicity of $\,e^{x+2\pi i}=e^x$

[image]

$$\oint=I(a)+I_1+I_2-e^{2\pi ia}I(a)=2\pi i Res_{x=\pi i}\frac{e^{ax}}{1 + e^x}$$
It can be shown that $I_1$ and $I_2\to0$ at $R\to\infty$. We have a single simple pole inside the contour at $x=e^{\pi i}$, therefore
$$I(a)(1-e^{2\pi ia})=-2\pi i e^{i\pi a}$$
$$I(a)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi a)}$$

Comment: Ok I'm wondering where is the integral of $C_R$  here and exactly as already said Rhaena, for me $\pi i $ is not a singular point, so I don't understand why you say that $e^{\pi i }$ is a pole

Comment: $e^{\pi i}=-1$, therefore $\frac{1}{1 + e^x}$ has a pole: $\frac{1}{1 + e^{\pi i+\epsilon}}=\frac{1}{1 -e^{\epsilon}}\to\frac{1}{1-1-\epsilon}=-\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ at $\epsilon\to$.

Comment: yes, this is not a semicircle - but is another, rectangular outline, where $|I_1|=|\int_R^{R+2\pi i} \frac{e^{ax}}{1 + e^x}dx|<\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{aR}}{\sqrt{(1+e^R\cos x)^2+e^{2R}\sin^2x}}dx<Const* e^{a-R}\to 0$ at $R\to\infty$. In the same way we evaluate that $I_2\to 0$ at $R\to\infty$

Comment: Ok, I see, of course, it is a singular point sorry for this stupid question. And thank you for your explanation for $I_1$ and $I_2$, but now, I'm sorry but why did you substract : $e^{2\pi i a}I(a)$

Comment: Integral along the closed contour consists of $I(a), I_1, I_2$ and integral along the line from $R+2\pi i$ to $-R+2\pi i$ (in the opposite direction). $\int_{R+2\pi i}^{-R+2\pi i} \frac{e^{ax}}{1 + e^x}dx=-\int_{-R+2\pi i}^{R+2\pi i} \frac{e^{ax}}{1 + e^x}dx=-\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{e^{a(t+2\pi i)}}{1 + e^(t+2\pi i)}dt=-e^{2\pi ia}\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{e^{at}}{1 + e^t}dt\to-e^{2\pi ia}I(a)$ - when we make change $x=t+2\pi i$

Comment: I'm sorry but there is something that I don't understand, in my notation that means we have : $I(a) = \int_{\gamma_R} f(x)dx - I_1 - I_2 + e^{2\pi i a}I(a) $, why ? I don't understand your division of the integral. Does it means that $- I_1 - I_2 + e^{2\pi i a}I(a) 
 = C_R $?

Answer (score 4):

I'm bad with contour integration, but this is another way of evaluating the integral.

Let's separate the integral in 2 parts $I=I_1+I_2$:

$$I_1=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{a x}dx}{e^x+1}$$

$$I_2=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{(1-a) x}dx}{e^x+1}$$

Clearly, both integrals have the same form just with $a \to 1-a$.

Let's find $I_1$:

$$I_1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^\infty e^{-(n+1-a) x} dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1-a}$$

So our integrals are:

$$I_1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1-a}=\frac{1}{2} \left[\psi \left(1-\frac{a}2 \right)-\psi \left(\frac12-\frac{a}2  \right) \right]$$

$$I_2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+a}=\frac{1}{2} \left[\psi \left(\frac12+\frac{a}2 \right)-\psi \left(\frac{a}2 \right) \right]$$

Where we used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function and one of its series definition.

We have, using reflection formula:

$$\psi \left(1-\frac{a}2 \right)=\psi \left(\frac{a}2 \right)+\pi \cot \frac{\pi a}{2}$$

$$\psi \left(\frac12-\frac{a}2  \right)=\psi \left(\frac12+\frac{a}2 \right)+\pi \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi a}{2} \right)$$

Collecting all the terms, we now have:

$$I=\frac{\pi}{2} \left( \cot \frac{\pi a}{2} -\cot \left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi a}{2} \right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{2} \left( \cot \frac{\pi a}{2} +\tan \frac{\pi a}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi a}$$

Clearly, this is not a satisfactory answer, since the most clear proof of the reflection formula comes from complex analysis. Still, I hope this might be helpful.

Comment: Didn't you consider also the gaussian hypergeometric function ? It is not bad. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, while I love Hypergeometric function, in this case Digamma is better, at least I think it is, since it's a little more "elementary" :)

Comment: I agree with you with repect to elementary functions. I asked the question because I know how much you love hypergeometric functions

Comment: a nice solution (+1)

Comment: @Svyatoslav, thanks, yours is certainly better. One ot these days I'll learn how to use contours and poles and such

Comment: @YuriyS. Contour integration is not difficult, but skills of usage digamma function tools worth much, in my opinion.

Comment: I'm so sorry I never seen this diagram but is there is another way to find the integrals ?

Answer (score 1):

$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}\,dx$$

$u=1+e^x\Rightarrow dx=du/e^x=du/(u-1)$ so:
$$I(a)=\int_1^\infty\frac{(u-1)^a}{u(u-1)}du=\int_1^\infty(u-1)^{a-1}u^{-1}\,du$$
and this wouldnt be too hard to write in terms of the incomplete beta function so you could express it as the limit of that?